# OpenCVの背景差分のプログラム

Tags: python, opencv

opencvで背景差分を行ったところ

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 269
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sabun5.py", line 16, in <module>
img_m = cv2.threshold(img_df, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:269: error: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function Mat
```

というエラーが出てきました。このエラーはどういう意味なのでしょうか。プログラム言語はPythonです。

Comment: コードも（出来れば[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能な](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)形で）質問に記載すると回答が得られ易いです。

Comment: 質問の編集とアドバイスありがとうございます。画像のパス表記を訂正したところ、正常に実行できました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/60011

Answer (score 1):

画像のパス表記を訂正したところ、正常に実行できました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @user7341567 さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31408/#comment30441_31408)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>